# Using Group By after selecting fields from another entity

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

I've a linq statement.

```
GalleryMedias
.Where(q => q.Gallery.Status == 1 && q.Media.Status == 1 && q.Media.MediaTypeId==1)
 .Select(q => new
{
   Id = q.Gallery.Id,
   Title = q.Gallery.Title,
   MediaTypeId = q.Media.MediaTypeId
 }
)
.OrderByDescending(q=>q.Id)
```

As you see, there is a relation between GalleryMedias and Gallery.I take fields from Gallery and Media. My result is currently looks like that.

```
Id  Title    MediaTypeId
355 record1  1
355 record1  1
354 record2  1
354 record2  1
353 record3  1
```

So, i want to group by them after selecting. But fields doesn't come from GalleryMedias so i cannot make group by.

How can i do it?

Comment: Didn't understand a thing from your question ... Could you make it a bit more clear, maybe by providing sample input and output?

Comment: I think I know what you're trying to say, see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Fields are not available from your GalleryMedias source after the Select because you have selected into a collection of anonymous objects that have no reference to the GalleryMedias source.

If you want to pull through all of the other GalleryMedias properties in order to use them in a GroupBy, you could do something similar the following example, where the GalleryMedias source objects are pulled through in the Select statement.

```
GalleryMedias
.Where(q => q.Gallery.Status == 1 && q.Media.Status == 1 && q.Media.MediaTypeId==1)
 .Select(q => new
{
   Id = q.Gallery.Id,
   Title = q.Gallery.Title,
   MediaTypeId = q.Media.MediaTypeId,
   GalleryMedia = q //Here you are including the GalleryMedia object in your annonymous object
 }
)
.GroupBy(g => g.GalleryMedia.Property) //You can now access the GalleryMedia's properties in the GroupBy
.OrderByDescending(q=>q.Id)
```